# How could I get data for angular from handlebars when the page is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, handlebars.js, angularjs-ng-model

I render the handlebars template with data.

```
 var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
    .create({
        defaultLayout:'main',
        helpers: {
            section: function (name, options) {
                if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
                this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
                return null;
            }
        }
    });



// setup hbs
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(function (req,res,next) {

    next();
});

// serving homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.render('about', {
        lucky: "you are lucky."
    });
});
// 404
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});
// 500 
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});
// startup
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' +
        app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

In the client end, I use anuglarjs. How could I get the data 'lucky' at the page is open and handover to angular?

```
    <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="update()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Luck</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Lucky"
                                   ng-model="Lucky" value='{{lucky}}'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <div style="padding-left:300px">
                           <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the angular app, I want to handle the data to deal with something.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.update= function () {
        $scope.lucky = 'hello world, lucky guy!';
    };


});
```

The value is set 'you are lucky.'. But it doesn't show. I searched some simliar question. They say it is confilct with data binding.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to set the `value` attribute, however if you really need to use it should be just `value="{{lucky}}"` (without single quotes).

The main problem is that your `ngModel` is `Lucky` when it should be just `lucky`.

Here's a *working* **demo** based on your `code`:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

  myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lucky = 'initial value';
    
    $scope.update = function() {
      $scope.lucky = 'hello world, lucky guy!';
    };
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="update()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Luck</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Lucky" ng-model="lucky">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div style="padding-left:300px">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but actually the data want is from server,By the way, my server is nodejs, my template engine is handlebars. My problem is how to transfer the data from server to my angular app.I have updated my server code.